# Gtk file not found, [fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory #include <gtk/gtk.h>] on VS Code, Windows 10

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gtk, gtk3

I am experiencing the error below error when running a code with #include <gtk/gtk.h>

```
PS C:\Users\UserName\C_Code Projects\Test> gcc hello.c -o hello
hello.c:1:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gtk/gtk.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
```

I have installed msys2, gcc and downloaded gtk3, gtk4 and the base devel tools

I have tried various methods but to no avail, nothing has worked

I tried to include the paths returned from `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` but vs code throws an error, displaying that the files don't exist

My includepath is:

```
${workspaceFolder}\**
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\**
C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\**
C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\glib-2.0\include
```

The goal is to build a GUI based application on C (due to College Reasons), any alternatives methods to achieve this is appreciated too

Comment: What paths are returned form `pkg-config?  Where did you put these include paths? Is it VS Code configuration or your compiler configuration? Does VSCode throw an error or does the compiler throw an error?

Comment: @Gerhardh VS Code throws the error when compiling,
The Include Paths are from VS Code, if i put the paths i get from the pkg-config vs code throws the error "File doesn't exist"

Comment: The include path for VSCode does not affect the compiler. They are only used by Intellisense to parse function declarations etc.

Comment: @Gerhardh Ohhh i see that's why the error lines dissapeared but on compile time the file is not found I use do i need to include the include paths with the execution command ? I tired giving the same include paths but due to ** the process went on infinitely

Comment: The command "gcc hello.c -o hello" wont automatically find your libraries. You have to tell the compiler where those libraries are and where their header files can be found. I don't use pkg-config myself, i use cmake instead to generate projects. The following link looks like how you are supposed to use pkg-config https://linuxhint.com/pkg-config-linux-command/. and here is a reference for manually supplying GCC with that information: https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/an_introduction_to_gcc/gccintro_17.html

Comment: @RichardBamford i use windows, is there a guide with on pkg config based on windows ? Because I installed pkg config but when I run the command it return gtk4 is not is the PKG CONFIG PATH, any way for a  workaround ?

Comment: @Shadow_Knight I'm really not experienced with pkg config. I use cmake+vcpkg to generate visual studio projects instead. But, it looks like pkg config is for unix based operating systems so you might come across some issues using it with windows. try these alternatives instead; https://cmake.org/ or https://premake.github.io/ with https://vcpkg.io/en/index.html

Comment: @Gerhardh i used pkgconf and added all the given paths but the script still produces the same error
I even gave all the tasks.json locations too

Comment: I am not really familiar with gtk under Windows. Instead of describing what you did, you should show it. What paths were returned by that command, how did you add them to your compiler commands? What is your compiler command? Please edit your question to add all these relevant bits&pieces.